# pureftpd - login authentication failed

Tags: logs, opensuse, configuration, ftp, pure-ftpd

I am on openSUSE 10.2, using pure-ftpd v1.0.21

I've added new virtual user, but I cannot connect (password is ok)

Output of verbose log:

```
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [INFO] New connection from xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 220-Welcome to Pure-FTPd.
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 220-You are user number 1 of 10 allowed.
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] Command [user] [someuser]
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 331 User someuser OK. Password required
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] Command [pass] [<*>]
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 530 Login authentication failed
Apr 10 17:10:35 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [WARNING] Authentication failed for user [someuser]
Apr 10 17:10:41 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [INFO] Logout.
Apr 10 17:10:41 hostzzz pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.yyy.zzz.uuu) [DEBUG] 530 Logout.
```

It's an old production server, and apparently there are some ftp users who can connect, so it seems that's a new user problem only

Any ideas for further debugging? Some others logs to check? Some configuration to verify?

Answer (score 3):

Aargh!

From [README.Virtual-Users](http://download.pureftpd.org/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Virtual-Users) :

> You can add, modify and delete users with the previous commands, or by
>   editing /etc/pureftpd.passwd by hand. But the FTP server won't
>   consider the changes you make to that file, until you commit them.

So, simply

```
pure-pw mkdb
```

or

```
pure-pw passwd joe -m
```

did the job

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( Is there a minimum number of characters limit or something? I set password "test" so I'm 100% I'm not mistyping it when connecting.

Comment: In my case this did not work, I had to do: ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/40PureDB and it fixed the issue. Go figure.